# Performing a INSERT INTO ... SELECT with LINQ to SQL

Tags: linq-to-sql, bulkinsert

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to perform an "insert into ... select" type command with LINQ to SQL. A bit of LINQ to SQL code that would allow me to send one single SQL command to the database that would insert multiple rows into a given table.

For example, how to make LINQ to SQL send the following T-SQL statement to an SQL Server database?

```
INSERT INTO Table1 
SELECT Table2.column1 + 1 AS column1, Table2.column2 + 2 AS column2
WHERE Table2.column3 > 100
```

I could of course achieve this by using the `DataContext.ExecuteCommand` function but this would be executed immediately without taking advantage of the automatic transaction handling you get with `DataContext.SubmitChanges`. I have a series of updates besides this one and I would like them all rolledbacked in case of an error.

Any ideas?

UPDATE: Here's the actual code:

```
        var bs_prep =
            from b in dc.T_EDR_FILEBODies
            join
            unpaid in dc.V_UNPAIDs
            on
                b.NUM_ADC.Substring(1, 9) equals unpaid.NOCONT
            join
            acordo in dc.T_ACORDOS_RECOM_APREs
            on
                Convert.ToInt32(b.NUM_ADC.Substring(1, 9)) equals acordo.ID_Contrato
            where
                b.ID_EDR == id_edr
                &&
                (
                    unpaid.NUM_INCUMPRIMENTOS <= max_unpaid_consec
                    &&
                    unpaid.TOTAL_NUM_INCUPRIMENTOS <= max_unpaid_nonconsec
                )
                ||
                (
                    acordo.Activo == true
                    &&
                    acordo.Data_Recomeco <= now
                )
            select new
                {
                    ID_EDR = id_edr_filt,
                    NUM_LINHA = b.NUM_LINHA,
                    CODREJ = b.CODREJ,
                    HDT = b.HDT,
                    IMPORT = b.IMPORT,
                    NIB_DEV = b.NIB_DEV,
                    NUM_ADC = b.NUM_ADC,
                    REF_DD_BC = b.REF_DD_BC,
                    REF_MOV = b.REF_MOV
                }
            ;


        dc.T_EDR_FILEBODies.InsertAllOnSubmit(
            bs_prep.Select(
                b => new T_EDR_FILEBODY{
                    CODREJ = b.CODREJ,
                    HDT = b.HDT,
                    ID_EDR = b.ID_EDR,
                    IMPORT = b.IMPORT,
                    NIB_DEV = b.NIB_DEV,
                    NUM_ADC = b.NUM_ADC,
                    NUM_LINHA = b.NUM_LINHA,
                    REF_DD_BC = b.REF_DD_BC,
                    REF_MOV = b.REF_MOV
                }
            )
        );
```

Quick explanation: 
The `T_EDR_FILEBODies` entity maps to a database table which basically stores the contents of some text files we import. One record corresponds to one line in the text file.

What I'm trying to do is create a filtered version of the file content by copying the records from one file, giving them a new file ID (`ID_EDR=id_edr_filt`) but filtering out some of the lines. 
The LINQ to SQL entities are direct mappings to the database tables. I have added no code to my datacontext so far. They do have primary keys, or otherwise I would not be able to do inserts on them (I read somewhere I would be able to get rid of that exception if I got rid of the primary keys but, as you can see, that would not work in my case).

When I run it I get the following exception thrown by `InsertAllOnSubmit`:

> Explicit construction of entity type 'T_EDR_FILEBODY' in query is not allowed.

I guess I understand that explicitally  constructing an entity inside a query would be problematic. Entities returned by queries have change tracking, changes are translated into the database when submitchanges is called. But how could you translate, into the database, changes on an entity created on the client side? But does this really mean you can't ever perform an INSERT INTO...SELECT type command using LINQ to SQL?

Comment: Can you do a "Using _tx as New TransactionScope()" and wrap the ExecuteCommand and whatever else in it?

Comment: Well I guess I can, and I might just be being picky but i find it hard to accept that you just cannot do a insert into...select statement using linq. It would be such a huge handycap.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
ctx.Table1.InsertAllOnSubmit(
    mySelectEnumeration.Select(x => new Table1DT { ... })
);
```

- `InsertAllOnSubmit` inserts a number of entries into a Linq to SQL table.
- `mySelectEnumeration` is the query that selects the items to be inserted.
- `Select(new Table1DT { ... })` is the transform required to convert the data type of you select query into the data type of the table.

Alternatively you can use the `ExecuteCommand` method and manage the transaction manually.

```
using (var ctx = new DataClasses1DataContext()) {
    ctx.Connection.Open();
    using (ctx.Transaction = ctx.Connection.BeginTransaction()) {
        ctx.ExecuteCommand("sqlcommand");
        ctx.Transaction.Commit();
    }
}
```

Or using the Transaction scope:

```
using (var ctx = new DataClasses1DataContext()) {
    using (var scope = new TransactionScope()) {
        ctx.ExecuteCommand("sqlcommand");
        scope.Complete();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I undertand your suggestion. I can't see how to initialize the Table1DT instance on the inline contructor based on mySelectEnumeration. How do i reference mySelectEnumeration?

Alternatively i tried to encapsulate the 1st query (which returns an IQueryable<Anonymous>) in another query with a Table1DT inline constructor on the Select clause and so returns a IQueryable<Table1DT>. But I get the same error i get putting the inline constructor in the 1st query:

Explicit construction of entity type 'Table1DT' in query is not allowed.

Comment: As I do not know your concrete DataContext class (ctx in my sample), I used placeholders. `Table1` is the placeholder for the table into the items should be inserted. `mySelectEnumeration` is the result of the query you do to select the items that you want to insert. `Table1DT` is the data type of your `Table1`. And, the `...` indicates where you will have to set the properties of "Table1", e.g. `ID = x.identifier`. I cannot be more specific without knowing your DataContext.

Comment: Ok my mistake, I guess i didn't read your reply as thoroughly as i should of (I missed the "x =>"). Ok tried that, and i still got the same exception on the InsertAllOnSubmit call: Explicit construction of entity type 'Table1DT' in query is not allowed. (I'm using the same notation you used). I've read about this and i got the idea that for some reason you cannot construct entities inside querys. Didn't quite get why though.

Comment: @Rui: Can you please post your code ... it's hard to guess what you are doing.